# USB 3 connection speed between MacBook and iPad

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, usb

I have a 2018 MacBook Pro with 4 USB 3 ports, supporting USB 3.1 Gen 2 (up to 10 Gbps)

And an iPad Air 2020 (4th Gen) with a USB 3 port, supporting up to 5 Gb/s apparently.

And I directly connect the two with a 10Gb/s rated USB 3 cable.

System Information tells me the two are connected with a «Up to 480 Mb/s» connection.

What’s wrong?

EDIT: tried same cable and same MacBook with an HTC mobile, and get «Up to 5Gb/s».  So it would seem that the USB port on the iPad doesn’t do more than 480Mb/s for data transfer to the Mac.